# Как использовать регулярные выражения для поиска многоточия?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
#Имеем текст
text = '''Шла Саша, значит, по шоссе и сосала... сушку!'''

#Имеем функцию, которая возвращает подстроку из строки, 
#Принимающая след.значения: текст[text]; номер первого элемента 
#подстроки[start]; Длину подстроки[size]. 
#Вне зависимости от размера size подстрока не должна обрываться.
#Она должна обязательно оканчиваться на знак препинания. Любой. 
#То есть многоточие не должно обрываться, а должно полностью войти в подстроку.
#Либо поиск [i-1] знака препинания должен "шагать" дальше, 
#пока "не упрется" в запятую.

def func(text: str, start: int, size: int) -> tuple(str, int):
        result = re.findall([регулярное выражение для поиска], text)
        print(result)
        symbols = ('.', ',', ':', ';', '!', '?')
        end = min(start + size, len(text))
        for i in range(end, start, -1):
                if text[i-1] in symbols or text[i-1] == result:
                        page = text[start:i].rstrip()
                        return page, len(page)

#Вывод подстроки и её длинны.     
print(func(text, 0, 37), sep='\n')
```

Прошу помочь!)))

Answer (score 3):

Точка это спецсимвол регулярки обозначающий любой символ, поэтому нужно либо так `[.]{3}`  в скобках символы не нуждаются в экранировании `{3}` - длина, либо так `\.\.\.` тут мы экранируем точки `\` таким образом они воспринимаются уже как обычный символ точки.

```
import re

text = "Шла Саша, значит, по шоссе и сосала... сушку!"
matches = re.finditer(r"\.\.\.", text, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print ("Найдено {matchNum} в позиции {start}-{end}: {match}"
      .format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), 
        end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

# Найдено 1 в позиции 35-38: ...
```

Comment: У меня видимо ошибка в логике функции... Не получается.

Comment: я привел небольшой пример, надеюсь сможете переделать под свою функцию

Comment: что касается логики то условие для многоточия как мне кажется должно быть таким `if text[i: i+3] == result[0]` а возврат таким `page = text[start:i + 3].rstrip()` в итоге `('Шла Саша, значит, по шоссе и сосала...', 38)`

Comment: А остальные символы в symbols?) Я вот и не понимаю, как миксануть оба условия.

Comment: можете сделать разные `if` в этом же цикле, просто троеточия проверяйте раньше иначе выскочите на первой точке

Comment: И если передать в качестве size = 34, то всё валится...

Comment: потому что у Вас не доходит до return в данном случае, в конце функции нужен по-любому ретурн с дефолтным возвратом

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Буду что-то думать)